# Generic type with specific key and value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am working on function which accepts two generic type parameters. One of those is `Object` type and another one is string extending `keyof` of passed object type. What I need is to somehow determine that provided `Object` must contain a key provided in second parameter and it's value also should be of specified type.

I tried something like this:

```js
const someFn = <
  T extends {[key: string]: number | null},
  K extends keyof T
>(data: T[], dataField: K) => {

  // expecting data values to be (number | null)[] for further purposes
  const dataValues = data.map(datum => datum[dataField]);

}
```

However code above works only if all keys in passed object are `number | null`

```js
type WorkingType = { value: number | null }
const workingArray = [{value: 1}, {value: null}]

someFn<WorkingType, "value">(workingArray, "value") // this works just fine
```

but if object containing field of different type i got error:

```js
type FailingType = { value: number | null, sthElse: string }
const workingArray = [{value: 1, sthElse: ""}, {value: null, sthElse}]

//. Property 'sthElse' is incompatible with index signature.
//   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | null'
someFn<FailingType, "value">(workingArray, "value")
```

so what I need to do is somehow provide inforrmation that only key proivided as `K` needs to be `number | null` I tried something like:

```js
const someFn<
  T extends { [key: T]: number | null },
  K extends keyof T
>(data: T[], dataKey: K) => {/* ... */}
```

But this seem to be not allowed by TS, I got `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'`. Is there any possible way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your point, anyway this is working for me:

```
    interface someFnI {
    <T,K extends keyof T>(data: T[], dataField: K);
}



const someFn = <
    T,
    K extends keyof T
>(data: T[], dataField: K) => {

    // expecting data values to be (number | null)[] for further purposes
const dataValues: T[K][] = data.map(datum => {
    return datum[dataField]});
    console.log(dataValues);

}

let myIdentity: someFnI = someFn;


type NotFailingType = { value: number | null, sthElse: string }
const workingArray = [
    { value: 1, sthElse: "" }, 
    { value: null, sthElse: null },
    //this will break as expected : uncomment below to check
    // { value: "notallowed", sthElse: null }
]

//. Property 'sthElse' is incompatible with index signature.
//   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | null'
myIdentity<NotFailingType, "value">(workingArray, "value")



type WorkingType = { value: number | null }
const workingArray2 = [{ value: 1 }, { value: null }]

myIdentity<WorkingType, "value">(workingArray2, "value")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Unfortunatelly. this solution does not work since typescript did not infere here that `dataValues` is `(number | null)[]` type and throw error when i try to use it.

Comment: I edit my answer and I've explicited the type (generics) of datavalues. const dataValues: T[K][] , but I dont get where you get error, I dont get any error using your data from your question. And actually datavalues is (number | null)[]